# Cannot Delete RegExp.$1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Anyone know why are the RegExp.$1-x variables are not settable to undefined?

Following example in nodejs. Same behavior in chrome/firefox:

```
console.log('1:', RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3, RegExp.$4); 
// 1: / Users/tiefenma/Desktop/ test.js .js

var string = 'test1 test2 test3';
var test = string.match(/(test1).*(test2).*(test3)/gm);


console.log('2:', RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3, RegExp.$4);
// 2: test1, test2, test3


RegExp.$1 = undefined;
RegExp.$2 = undefined;
RegExp.$3 = undefined;
console.log('3:', RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3, RegExp.$4);
// 3: test1, test2, test3


delete RegExp.$1;
delete RegExp.$2;
delete RegExp.$3;
console.log('4:', RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3, RegExp.$4);
// 4: test1, test2, test3


''.match(/(.*)/g);
console.log('5:', RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3, RegExp.$4);
// 5:
```

Comment: Please notice that those properties [are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties). Use the fields of the result (`test`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(RegExp, "$1")` will give you information about `$1`:

> Chrome 30:
>
> ```
> { 
>     get: function, 
>     set: function, 
>     enumerable: true, 
>     configurable: false
> }
> ```
>
> Firefox 22:
>
> ```
> {
>     configurable: false,
>     enumerable: true, 
>     value: "", 
>     writable: false
> }
> ```

Note that `configurable` is `false`; so, you can't delete the property. Also, when `writable` is `false`, you can't assign a value.

> **configurable**
>   true if and only if the type of this property descriptor
>   may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the
>   corresponding object.
>   **writable**
>   True if and only if the value associated with the property
>   may be changed with an assignment operator. **Defaults to `false`.**

So, in Chrome and Firefox, the implementation prevents you from deleting `$1` or assigning a value to `$1` with `=`.

As a point of comparison, IE10 reports things a little differently...

> Internet Explorer 10:
>
> ```
> {
>     value: "",
>     writable: true,
>     enumerable: false,
>     configurable: true
> }
> ```

That said, IE10 still won't let you delete the property or assign a value to it. Go figure.

Comment: If `writable` is missing, that doesn't mean you can't assign to it. It still might have a `set`ter function, only we don't know what that does.

Comment: @Bergi fair enough. I took too much from the _"Defaults to `false`"_ bit.